# Flex-column collapse on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, safari, flexbox

This question has been raised many times before but flex model has changed dramatically and I am still unable to find a working solution.

**THE PROBLEM**

- When the flex direction of an object is set to column, the height of all objects collapse *(i.e height:0)*
- The problem appears restricted to iProducts. As far as I can tell Flex works as expected in all browsers on desktop and on android.
- The problem is not restricted to Safari as the issue is present on Chrome and Firefox when tested on an iPad *(IOS 10.3.3)*.

This example demonstrates the issue. When width is less than 600px the rows switch to column and the issue will be present.

```css
.InputRow,
.InputItem,
.InputWrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.InputRow,
.InputItem {
  -ms-flex-flow: wrap;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.InputItem,
.InputWrap {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.InputWrap {
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

@media all and (max-width:600px) {
  .InputRow {
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}

.Bx {
  background: #b00;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="InputRow">
  <div class="InputItem">
    <div class="InputWrap">
      <div class="Bx">Box 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="InputItem">
    <div class="InputWrap">
      <div class="Bx">Box 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="InputRow">
  <div class="InputItem">
    <div class="InputWrap">
      <div class="Bx">ROW 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This could be an issue with the nesting structure I have setup here but as I said the issue is isolated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any heights defined, either on containers or items.

Yet, you are telling items to use free space:

```
.InputItem,
.InputWrap {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}
```

This rule breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0%`

The `flex-grow: 1` rule may work fine on wider screens (`flex-direction: row`) because the containers are block level elements (i.e., width: 100%).

But on smaller screens (`flex-direction: column`), `height` is set (via `flex-basis`) to `0%`, `flex-grow: 1` has no extra space to work, and the containers height (unlike its width) defaults to `auto` (content height).

So I think the solution is to add height to the container or the items.

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B  This is a logical answer that target the issue at hand. Adding height creates the desired result however specifying a fixed height would undermine the purpose of "flex" box because I want the height to dynamically adjust to it's content as it does on other devices.

Comment: Found the solution. It seems some genius has already created an outstanding answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644245/2120261